# Vector displacement with a zero digit

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Given a math example of: "A person walks 3km east, then 1.5km south west. What is the resultant displacement?"

[image]

The study guide provides these workings;

> A displacement of 3km east has x -component 3, y -component 0.
>
> A displacement of 1.5km south west has: $$x -component -1.5 cos 45 =
> > -1.06$$ $$y -component -1.5 cos 45 = -1.06$$
>
> The resultant has; 
>   $$x -component 3 - 1.06 = 1.94$$
>   $$y -component 0 -1.06 = -1.06$$

Why did the 3km displacement not get calculated similar to the 1.5?

example: $$3cos(45) + (-1.5)cos(45) = 2.12 + (-1.06)  = 1.06$$

$1.06$ instead of $1.94$. Does this have something to do with the y component of the 3km displacement being a $0$?

EDIT:

I tried Arthur's suggestion with a following example but it doesn't work?

> A plane with airspeed 200km/hour heads due north. A 100 km/hour north
>   east wind (coming from the north east) begins to blow.
>
> What is the resultant velocity of the plane relative to the ground?
>
> We use symbols:
>
> vPA = velocity of plane relative to air
>
> vAG = velocity of air relative to ground
>
> vPG = velocity of plane relative to ground = PA AG
>
> $$vPA : x - component: 0$$ 
>   $$y -component: 200$$ 
>   $$AG v : x - component - 100 cos 45 = -70.7$$ 
>   $$y - component - 100 cos 45 = -70.7$$

It's definitely something to do with the $0$ component right? I just don't know the rule or reasoning behind it to use it on everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *did* get calculated the same way:
$$
x: \quad 3\cdot \cos0=3\\
y: \quad 3\cdot\sin 0=0
$$
It is, however, almost trivial to see immediately from the drawing (and the text) that this is the result; going straight eastward will only ever change the $x$-component, and the change in the $x$-component must be equal to the distance walked. So they skipped the calculations in the study guide.

Comment: Hi Arthur. Is the 3cos0, that way because a straight line has no angle? So I was doing it wrong by using the 1.5km displacements 45 degree angle?

Comment: Hey Arthur, I am not sure your calculations holds true with something going directly north (y axis) with no horizontal movement. Because lets say, 200km north, with no horizontal movement. If I do 200sin(0) = 0, but the answer should be 200.

Comment: @Anon The angle we use is conventionally the angle between the walking direction and the pure $x$-ward direction (in this case eastward), with counterclockwise being positive and clockwise being negative. So the calculations your guide did should've been done with $-135^\circ$. That would've given the negative sign that they put there without explaining it. And pure north becomes $90^\circ$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That's a great explanation. I edited my question as you must have been writing this. I'll amend the question and mark this as the answer. Thank you again for being so helpful